# Replace does not work in some scenarios

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have the following string.

> We all know you can never have too many yoga pants!! Today's giveaway is with my fav @aloyoga \ud83d\ude0d \ud83c\udf81\ud83d\udcaa\ud83c\udffcI am honestly so proud of everyone who has been participating in the #JenSelterChallenge.. I have been overwhelmed by the level of commitment, progress, and positivity over the last couple of weeks. Seeing your photos and captions puts a huge smile on my face everyday. Thank you guys for making it such a success and for those who haven't joined yet, it's not too late! Congrats to the winners of WEEK 3\u2014 I will DM you all this weekend!! \ud83d\ude03 \n@Vicfitness_\n@Bodyroxxfit\n@Krvstah\n@Lvlelissa3\n@ThisIsNaila \n@X_i_a_r_a_\n@Btrevellini\n@Nicolesfitjourney_ \n#Seltering

I want to replace the \n with Environment.NewLine. So, I tried the following:

```
caption = caption.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Did not work. Nothing was changed. I tried at the previous step when I declare it also,

```
caption = Regex.Match(response, pattern).Groups[1].Value.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Also didn't work.

However, when I manually try to input the string like this:

```
string test = "We all know you can never have too many yoga pants!! Today's giveaway is with my fav @aloyoga \ud83d\ude0d \ud83c\udf81\ud83d\udcaa\ud83c\udffcI am honestly so proud of everyone who has been participating in the #JenSelterChallenge.. I have been overwhelmed by the level of commitment, progress, and positivity over the last couple of weeks. Seeing your photos and captions puts a huge smile on my face everyday. Thank you guys for making it such a success and for those who haven't joined yet, it's not too late! Congrats to the winners of WEEK 3\u2014 I will DM you all this weekend!! \ud83d\ude03 \n@Vicfitness_\n@Bodyroxxfit\n@Krvstah\n@Lvlelissa3\n@ThisIsNaila \n@X_i_a_r_a_\n@Btrevellini\n@Nicolesfitjourney_ \n#Seltering";
test.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

It works fine. But I'm not sure what is different when I hard-code the string and when I get it normally. It's the exactly same string, I have checked it myself by debugging. Is there something I'm not aware of?

Comment: How are you "getting it normally"?

Comment: Probably but based on what you've posted here we wouldn't be able to tell you what it is.  Please make sure to create a [MCVE].

Comment: It's probably the fact that you're escaping `\n`. You need `\\n`, at least looking at your string.

Comment: use the literal string perhaps? `@"\n"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do "\n" that gets turned in to the single character `0x0A`. What it looks like you actually want are the two characters "\" and "n" next to each other.

Put a `@` in front of your replace string and it will stop translating the `\n` to 0x0A

```
caption = caption.Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

You could also do it by escaping the slash

```
caption = caption.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you. I will make sure to escape the characters next time.

Comment: The best way to thank someone is to upvote their answer/accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you do `caption.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);`?

It looks like your string is not containing the newline character '\n' but a string composed by a backslash followed by the character `n`.